# PHP script not executing on Apache server. U-18.4 PHP 7.2 Localhost

Tags: server, apache2, php, localhost

My Apache is running and displays the Default Page.  I can redirect a PHP file into php and the echo command displays properly.
I've already researched previous versions of Ubuntu and can't find any solution.

```
a2query -m php7.2  -> Enabled by maintainer script
```

In `/etc/apache2/mods-avaliable/php7.2.conf`

```
These lines have been commented.
 Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default
 To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
 (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
 prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
  Commented following lines.
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_flag engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

The classic phpinfo.php processes but no output is provided by Apache. i.e. `php < phpinfo.php`  lists all the information.

I believe that there is a setting required and/or a value not set.
This resulted after upgrading from Ubuntu 15.04 to Ubuntu 18.04.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the *actual* problem? `<?php echo "Foo bar" ?>` works, but `phpinfo()` does not?

Comment: Trying to load a file called test.php containing <?php echo "Foo bar" will not display via Firefox, but  command line php < test.php will display correctly.

Comment: Same for phpinfo.php.   Will not display if accessed via browser, but php < phpinfo.php will provide complete textual output.

Comment: Where is the script you're trying to call via the browser located?

Comment: /home/*/public_html/phpinfo.php.    I might add that file:////var/www/html/phpinfo.php  access by Firefox wants to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

In file /etc/apache2/envvars the user and group were not correct.
changed export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data  to myname
and changed export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data to myname

Other changes were made to the apache configuration file to get phpmyadmin to work, but that's another story.

Comment: Unfortunately this had no effect for me. After running through [install-php-7-2-18-04](https://thishosting.rocks/install-php-on-ubuntu/#install-php-7-2-18-04), I then just ran `sudo a2enmod php7.2 && sudo systemctl restart apache2` per [how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04?comment=70395). (The first site also had `a2enmod php7.2`, but it was under the section, 'How to change the PHP version you’re using'.)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem with php files not being executed after an upgrade from Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.10 and php 7.3. It turns out that this question was my answer. My Web root was in /home/xyz/public_html. The solution was to comment the block `<IfModule mod_userdir.c> ... </IfModule>`.